# map a path to a subfolder in tsconfig

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

in tsconfig.paths we map aliases to real paths.
I want to do something like this without using barrels i.e. reexporting from an index.ts file

tsconfig.json

```
paths{
 "lib/*/*": ["./lib/*/src/*"]
}
```

the problem here is that typescript doesn't allow the use of multiple wildcards here,
I also tried the glob pattern `lib/**/*` but the same issue occurs.

Comment: I don't think you can do this - you would have to list all the paths separately i.e. `lib/foo/src/*: ..., lib/bar/src/*: ..., lib/baz/src/*...` and so on.